# Temporary disable e-mail when ownership is assigned

Tags: 2010

I have the following problem. For some reasons we need to create a new task list in sharepoint. The task is created via the template. We would like to inform the users, when sombebody creates a new task and assign the task to a specific person. The function "E-Mail Notification, Send e-mail when ownership is assigned or when an item has been changed." is working fine for that demand.

Here is my problem: We would like to copy all finished or withdrawn tasks from the old task list to the new one. Even if I copy/paste all the old task via data sheet view to the new list, sharepoint sends an email for every copied task to the user. In the end, a few hundred mails would be send to the user because of the "new" ownership for the old tasks.

So I tried the following: I disabled the mail-when-new-ownership feature and copy/pasted all the old finished tasks in the new list. Still, after reactivating, Sharepoint sends all the mails.

My last try: I once disabled the mail-when-new-ownership feature and copy/pasted all the old finished tasks in the new list. Then I created manually a new task in the new list and assigned it to me. Afterwards, I reactivated the email-feature. It seems like it is working: I am the only one, who gets an email for a new ownerships. Sharepoint ignores the old stuff.

My question: Am I just lucky or is this a possible solution for my problem? Deactivate the feature -> Copy paste the old stuff -> manually create a task, assign it to me -> reactivate the feature. I hope, sombeody could reproduce my problem or could confirm the suggested solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I created webpart that disabled/enabled alerts from current web.

In Your case You can try to temporarily disable alerts with [stsadm](http://noambaum.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-enable-or-disable-sharepoint.html).

Test it first, and pay attention that by default alert sends [every 5 minutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862631(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection2), so if You turn on alerts immidiately, they could be sended(wait for 5 minutes before turn on)